# How to disable half-hiding output, when the corresponding input cell is modified

Tags: front-end, editing

I think it has become less easy to compare the new output, now that the output font color turns gray as soon as something is modified in the input cell. Is there any solution?

Comment: An annoying feature, I agree.

Comment: I agree with you, I think of it more like a bug than a feature. I'd also like to find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a style associated with this behavior, that you can disable by evaluating

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {PrivateCellOptions, "EvaluationUnmatchedStyle"}] = {}
```

To re-enable the behavior, set the value to `Inherited`:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {PrivateCellOptions, "EvaluationUnmatchedStyle"}] = Inherited
```

Comment: How would you use this option so that it is set forever and survives restarts?

Comment: In more recent M10 versions, there should be an entry in the Options inspector, which you could set in your global preferences(just search for EvaluationUnmatchedStyle).